# How do you package JavaFX within a .exe file created by Launch4j?

Tags: java, javafx, launch4j

I am trying to create a JavaFX application, but I cannot find a way to bundle the JavaFX jar files within the EXE file created by Launch4j. Is there a way to do this?

What I have so far is an EXE and a distribution of OpenJFX 14 and OpenJDK 14 in the same folder with JRE path and VM options as dictated by the OpenJFX documentation.

I am using OpenJDK 14.0.1 with Open JavaFX 14.0.2.

Comment: JavaFX is more than just a set of jar files; it relies on native graphical components as well. You can't(*) just include the jar files in your application and make it work. You need to create a JVM which has JavaFX included and then use that JVM to create the native .exe package. The jlink tool included in Java11 and later will do this  ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm)). Note you can also use [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/) instead of Launch4j to build the native package; this will actually run jlink for you.

Comment: (*) There are apparently some hacks which will make it work if you just include the JavaFX jars, but you are strongly encouraged not to rely on these.

Comment: I am wondering why we have to answer this same question over and over again roughly every 24 hours.

Comment: @James_D, thank you for the information. I'll try it out!

Comment: @mipa I have not seen this question on this forum in this particular form, that is why I asked. If I had seen another like this, I would have used it.

Comment: @mipa A comprehensive community wiki Q&A might be in order, though I don’t think I have quite enough knowledge to do that.

Comment: As James_D suggests, jpackage is a great way to build EXE for JavaFX applications. You can use jlink to generate a runtime with precisely the JavaFX dependencies you use (example: `jlink --module-path "pathtojavafx-jmods-14;mods" --add-modules javafx.controls --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --compress=1 --output myjre.with.javafx`) and use jpackage to make EXE with that cutdown JRE.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by extracting required library in generated `jar` while creating runnable

Select option like this:

[image: Library handling]

After it, perform simple `launch4j` steps to create `.exe`