Generated .exe not working (Standalone program written in Javafx, Scenebuilder)
I have written a simple calculator program in Javafx and scenebuilder in Eclipse IDE.
It is running well. Also I can create .JAR file by Launch4J. This jar is also running in command promt with the JVM arguments which I used in run as->argument portion
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\openjfx-22.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-22.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
But when I am creating .exe in Launc4j that .exe file is not working.
I tried keeping the entire jdk folder, jre folder, javafx folder in my application creation folder.
In my windows under program files I have the detail below
I have the foledrs under program files as PROGRAM FILES->JAVA->JDK-1.8, JDK-22, JDK-22.0.2, JRE1.8.0_421, javafx-sdk-22.0.2.
(I have the javafx folder under program files->java->openjfx-22.0._2_windows-x64_bin-sdk->javafx-sdk-22.0.2)
Stil .exe is not working

Was the appropriate native code of JavaFX (some or all of the *.dll files in the bin directory of the JavaFX SDK on Windows) included?

I have included entire java into my exe creation folder.Executing: D:\MYPROGRAM\application-jarfile\calculatormadeeasy\CalculatorMadeEasy.exe
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application sometimes getting error AJAVA EXCEPTION OCCURRED

Sorry @Abra i accidently flagged you.I didnt mean to i just did not do what this falg does.Sorry for the inconvinience.Hope you understand.

Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602518/how-do-you-package-javafx-within-a-exe-file-created-by-launch4j?rq=2

A "runtime components are missing" error indicates you have not configured Launch4j to output an application that resolves JavaFX as named modules (i.e., that places JavaFX on the module-path instead of the class-path). But since I'm not familiar with Launch4j, I don't know how to fix that. But one workaround you can try is to create a separate main class that is not a subclass of Application and which simply launches the JavaFX application.

Example Tree

Use IDE NetBeans crate a JavaFX Example App.
Add Log4j function

demofxapp
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   ├── com
        │   │   └── example
        │   │       └── demofxapp
        │   │           ├── App.java
        │   │           ├── PrimaryController.java
        │   │           └── SecondaryController.java
        │   └── module-info.java
        ├── launch4j
        │   ├── DemoApp_LocalDir.xml
        │   └── logo.ico
        └── resources
            ├── com
            │   └── example
            │       └── demofxapp
            │           ├── primary.fxml
            │           └── secondary.fxml
            └── log4j2.xml

module-info.java
module com.example.demofxapp {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    opens com.example.demofxapp to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.demofxapp;
}

App.java
Change: Only Add log4j function.
package com.example.demofxapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

    private static Scene scene;

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        logger.info("setRoot");
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        logger.info("loadFXML");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("launch");
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        logger.info("start");
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("DemoApp");
        stage.show();
    }

}

PrimaryController.java
Change: Only Add log4j function.
package com.example.demofxapp;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;

public class PrimaryController {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PrimaryController.class);

    @FXML
    private void switchToSecondary() throws IOException {
        logger.info("switchToSecondary");
        App.setRoot("secondary");
    }
}

SecondaryController.java
package com.example.demofxapp;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SecondaryController {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SecondaryController.class);

    @FXML
    private void switchToPrimary() throws IOException {
        logger.info("switchToPrimary");
        App.setRoot("primary");
    }
}

primary.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demofxapp.PrimaryController">
   
   <children>
      <Label text="Primary View" />
      <Button fx:id="primaryButton" text="Switch to Secondary View" onAction="#switchToSecondary"/>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>

secondary.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demofxapp.SecondaryController">
    <children>
        <Label text="Secondary View" />
        <Button fx:id="secondaryButton" text="Switch to Primary View" onAction="#switchToPrimary" />
    </children>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>
</VBox>

log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console Appender Configuration -->
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <!-- File Appender Configuration -->
        <File name="File" fileName="logs/app.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- Root Logger Configuration -->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>

        <!-- Application Specific Logger Configuration -->
        <Logger name="com.example" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

DemoApp_LocalDir.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
    <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
    <headerType>gui</headerType>
    <jar>demofxapp.jar</jar>
    <outfile>demofxapp.exe</outfile>
    <errTitle>Demo FX App</errTitle>
    <cmdLine></cmdLine>
    <chdir>.</chdir>
    <priority>normal</priority>
    <downloadUrl></downloadUrl>
    <supportUrl></supportUrl>
    <stayAlive>true</stayAlive>
    <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
    <manifest></manifest>
    <icon>logo.ico</icon>
    <jre>
        <path>jre</path>
        <requiresJdk>false</requiresJdk>
        <requires64Bit>true</requires64Bit>
        <minVersion></minVersion>
        <maxVersion></maxVersion>
        <opt>-Dlog4j.configurationFile=conf/log4j2.xml</opt>
    </jre>
</launch4jConfig>

logo.ico
you can use your icon file.
pom.xml
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demofxapp</artifactId>
    <name>demofxapp</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j2 core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j2 API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs\</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.example.demofxapp.App
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>conf/log4j2.xml</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}\libs</outputDirectory>
                    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- `mvn clean package exec:exec@jlink-build-jre` -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jlink-build-jre</id>
                        <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>jlink</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--strip-debug</argument>
                                <argument>--no-man-pages</argument>
                                <argument>--no-header-files</argument>
                                <argument>--compress=2</argument>
                                <argument>--module-path</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/libs</argument>
                                <argument>--add-modules</argument>
                                <argument>
                                    java.base,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls,org.apache.logging.log4j,org.apache.logging.log4j.core
                                </argument>
                                <argument>--output</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/dist/app/jre</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- `mvn exec:exec@launch4j-build-app-exe` -->

                    <execution>
                        <id>launch4j-build-app-exe</id>
                        <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\launch4jc.exe"</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}\dist\app\DemoApp_LocalDir.xml</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.demofxapp.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000
                                </option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run Command
                     `mvn resources:copy-resources@prepare-launch4j-resources`
                       -->
                    <!-- copy-resources , after jlink-build-app-jre-->
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-launch4j-resources</id>
                        <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist/app</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/launch4j</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>logo.ico</include>
                                        <include>DemoApp_LocalDir.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>demofxapp.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- Run Command
                     `mvn resources:copy-resources@prepare-launch4j-resources-conf`
                       -->
                    <!-- copy-resources , after jlink-build-app-jre -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-launch4j-resources-conf</id>
                        <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist/app/conf</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>log4j2.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Build
mvn clean package

you can find output:

create demofxapp.jar
create libs include dependency jar

target
├── demofxapp.jar
└── libs
    ├── javafx-base-21.jar
    ├── javafx-base-21-linux.jar
    ├── javafx-base-21-win.jar
    ├── javafx-controls-21.jar
    ├── javafx-controls-21-linux.jar
    ├── javafx-controls-21-win.jar
    ├── javafx-fxml-21.jar
    ├── javafx-fxml-21-linux.jar
    ├── javafx-fxml-21-win.jar
    ├── javafx-graphics-21.jar
    ├── javafx-graphics-21-linux.jar
    ├── javafx-graphics-21-win.jar
    ├── log4j-api-2.23.1.jar
    └── log4j-core-2.23.1.jar

maven-jar-plugin

config jar as executable jar
add dependency jat to classpath


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs\</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>
                    com.example.demofxapp.App
                </mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>conf/log4j2.xml</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>               

maven-dependency-plugin
download dependency jar to target/libs
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}\libs</outputDirectory>
        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

create app jre
mvn exec:exec@jlink-build-jre

create folder target/dist/app/jre
target
└── dist
    └── app
        └── jre (85 MB)

It is same as command line:
jlink ^
  --module-path target\libs ^
  --add-modules java.base,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls,org.apache.logging.log4j,org.apache.logging.log4j.core ^
  --strip-debug ^
  --no-man-pages ^
  --no-header-files ^
  --compress=2 ^
  --output target\dist\app\jre

NOTE: In Windows, the newline symbol for command-line instructions is ^. This notation can be used to break a long instruction into multiple lines.
use exec-maven-plugin do the same thing.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- `mvn clean package exec:exec@jlink-build-jre` -->
        <execution>
            <id>jlink-build-jre</id>
            <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>jlink</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>--strip-debug</argument>
                    <argument>--no-man-pages</argument>
                    <argument>--no-header-files</argument>
                    <argument>--compress=2</argument>
                    <argument>--module-path</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/libs</argument>
                    <argument>--add-modules</argument>
                    <argument> java.base,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls,org.apache.logging.log4j,org.apache.logging.log4j.core
                    </argument>
                    <argument>--output</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/dist/app/jre</argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

Prepare Launch4j Work Diectory:
mvn ^
  resources:copy-resources@prepare-launch4j-resources ^ 
  resources:copy-resources@prepare-launch4j-resources-conf

Get output
target/dist/app
├── DemoApp_LocalDir.xml (*Launch4j)
├── logo.ico             (*Launch4j)
├── demofxapp.jar
├── conf
│   └── log4j2.xml
└── jre

Create Launch4j EXE
mvn exec:exec@launch4j-build-app-exe

get output: demofxapp.exe
target/dist/app
├── DemoApp_LocalDir.xml (*Launch4j)
├── logo.ico             (*Launch4j)
├── demofxapp.jar
├── demofxapp.exe 
├── conf
│   └── log4j2.xml
└── jre

Same Terminal Command:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\launch4jc.exe"  C:\Users\IEUser\Documents\demofxapp\target\dist\app\DemoApp_LocalDir.xml

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
    
        <!-- `mvn exec:exec@launch4j-build-app-exe` -->
        <execution>
            <id>launch4j-build-app-exe</id>
            <!-- <phase>package</phase> -->
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Launch4j\launch4jc.exe"</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}\dist\app\DemoApp_LocalDir.xml</argument>
                </arguments>
                <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

Clean dist app directory
PLEASE DELETE THESE FILES.
target/dist/app
├── DemoApp_LocalDir.xml (*DELETE)
├── logo.ico             (*DELETE)
├── demofxapp.jar        (*DELETE) 

final dist directory
app
├── demofxapp.exe
├── conf
│   └── log4j2.xml
└── jre

Now you can copy the entire app directory to other environments without JDK or JRE installed for execution.
Install App to Other Windows

copy app to C:\TOOLS

check jre modules
java --list-modules

JDK, JavaFX, Log4j
Result:
C:\Users\IEUser>cd C:\TOOLS\app\jre\bin

C:\TOOLS\app\jre\bin>java --list-modules
java.base@17.0.11
java.compiler@17.0.11
java.datatransfer@17.0.11
java.desktop@17.0.11
java.logging@17.0.11
java.management@17.0.11
java.prefs@17.0.11
java.rmi@17.0.11
java.scripting@17.0.11
java.xml@17.0.11
javafx.base@21
javafx.controls@21
javafx.fxml@21
javafx.graphics@21
jdk.unsupported@17.0.11
org.apache.logging.log4j@2.23.1
org.apache.logging.log4j.core@2.23.1

Screen
Run exe

Check log file

You can modify conf\log4j2.xml to change log format.
Environment:

Windows 10
JDK 17 (OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_17.0.11_9.msi)
Maven 9
Launch4j (launch4j-3.50-win32.exe)

